How to Implement Safe Core Security in a Smart Contract on Sepolia Network?
I am currently developing a smart contract on the Sepolia network and I want to enhance its security using Safe Core. I have some familiarity with basic smart contract development in Solidity but I am new to Safe Core's security features.
Could anyone provide a detailed guide on how to integrate Safe Core into my existing smart contract? Specifically, I am looking for:
An overview of what Safe Core offers in terms of security.
Step-by-step instructions on how to implement Safe Core in a Solidity smart contract.
Any relevant code examples or best practices.
Information on testing the implementation on the Sepolia testnet.
Additionally, if there are any common pitfalls or things to watch out for during the integration, that advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
